# changing the location of the settings file

Tags: c#, .net, settings

Is it possible to override the location for the settings file used in c#. It would be easier to locate the settings file to a common location so that it can be shared across different applications.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just came across the problem that under win7 and vista .exes running without admin privs can't write to the config file. Strange that by default VS puts it in a place it shouldn't be. I just opted for using xml files and storing them in the LocalApplicationData folder. A while back I [wrote a blog entry](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2008/12/reasons-to-avoid-visual-studios.html) on reasons to avoid using the app.config file, now I have one more and you have another one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a project called `GlobalResources` in visual studio and put resources in this project, as well as those classes that are used to manage these resources. Then you can add the project as a reference to other projects in the solution.

Comment: The settings file are created on a application basis even if a shared project is created, so i would like to override that.